# (Mysql) Insert data using Store Procedure with nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

**I write this code, but I can't know why this code have error with mysql db when I'm trying with store procedure in mysql:**

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "8889",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "ResetAccountTest"
});

con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
       console.log('Error connecting to Database');
       return;
    } console.log('Connection established');
});

var accountTest = { email: 'mra@fpt.edu.vn', password: 'root', bit: '1' };
con.query('call newAccount(?, ?, ?)', accountTest, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(result.insertId);
});

con.end(function(err) {
// The connection is terminated gracefully
// Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
// before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
});
```

**This's error:**

```
Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:48:14)
at Query.ErrorPacket (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
at Protocol._parsePacket (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:274:23)
at Parser.write (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:77:12)
at Protocol.write (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:96:28)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:146:16)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:110:10)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
at Connection.query (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:201:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mikegraham/Documents/WebstormProjects/reset-password/app.js:20:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:457:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:972:3
```

**Sorry guys, I'm a beginner with nodejs. I hope community can help me solved this problem :D**

Comment: make a variable of con.query, 'var sql = con.query('call newAc....')', console.log that variable as: console.log(sql.sql). This outputs the query after being processed. You will probably find the error in this output.

Comment: execute on mysql client (phpmyadmin or other) this command: call newAccount('mra@fpt.edu.vn', 'root', '1'); check result function. May be problem in your sql code in function;

Comment: Yes I can solved this. Many thanks Billy :D

Comment: I solved this with change Line 20: var sql = con.query('call newAccount(?, ?, ?)', [accountTest.email, accountTest.password, accountTest.bit], function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(result.insertId);
});

Comment: can you please create an answer to your own question so we can most likely upvote it and you can mark it as Answered? The parameter passing part. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I solved this with change Line 20: var sql = con.query('call newAccount(?, ?, ?)', [accountTest.email, accountTest.password, accountTest.bit], function(err, result) { if (err) throw err; console.log(result.insertId); });**

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    port: "8889",
    user: "root",
    password: "root",
    database: "ResetAccountTest"
});

con.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
       console.log('Error connecting to Database');
       return;
    } console.log('Connection established');
});

var sql = con.query('call newAccount(?, ?, ?)', [accountTest.email, accountTest.password, accountTest.bit], function(err, result) { 
      if (err) throw err; 
      console.log(result.insertId); 
});

con.end(function(err) {
// The connection is terminated gracefully
// Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
// before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
});
```