# How to solve ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR in node mysql stored procedure?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

im receiving an error  when running this code `Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'employee_id' in 'field list'`

the output is this

```
  { employee_id: '6',
    employee_name: 'test',
    employee_contact: 'test' }
```

this is my stored procedure code

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `test3`( 
       in empid int(11) ,
       in name1 varchar(45) ,
       in contact varchar(45)
    )
    BEGIN
      insert into test_table (employee_id  , employee_name , employee_contact) values (empid,name1,contact);
    END
```

this is my index.js

```
router.post('/test', function (req, res, next) {
    try {
        var reqObj = req.body;
        console.log(reqObj);
        req.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
            if (err) {
                console.error('SQL Connection error: ', err);
                return next(err);
            } else {
                // let  employee_id = reqObj.employee_id
                //  let employee_name =reqObj.name1
                //  let  employee_contact = reqObj.contact
               var insertSql6 = "CAll test3(employee_id, employee_name, employee_contact)";
               var insertValues6 = { 
                   "employee_id": reqObj.empid,
                   "employee_name": reqObj.name1, 
                   "employee_contact": reqObj.contact
               };
                var query = conn.query(insertSql6,insertValues6, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) { 
                        console.error('SQL error: ', err);
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    console.log(result);
                    var test_Id = result.insertId;
                    res.json({
                        "test_id": test_Id 
                    });
                });
            } 
        }); 
    } catch (ex) { 
        console.error("Internal error:" + ex); 
        return next(ex);
    }
});
```

Comment: Pretty self-explanatory — you don't have a field in your database called `employee_id`.

Comment: @brandonscript i have a employee_id field in my database..thats why im too confuse why im having that error

Comment: @michaeljohnperalta show your table structure

Comment: employee_id int (11)
employee_name varchar(45)
employee_contact varchar(45)

sorry i dont know how to show it here i just type the fieldname and the data type sorry still newbie here

Comment: Here is an example Stack Overflow post for calling stored procedure with parameters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33918511/mysql-insert-data-using-store-procedure-with-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes to the arguments inside the insertSql6 string.

Before:

```
var insertSql6 = "CAll test3(employee_id, employee_name, employee_contact)";
```

After:

```
var insertSql6 = "CAll test3('employee_id', 'employee_name', 'employee_contact')";
```